# Submitting a streaming job to a spark cluster via a Spark Context

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an `operation: RDD[T] => Unit` that I would like to submit as a spark job, using a spark `streamingContext`.  The Spark job should stream values from `myStream`, passing each instance of `RDD[T]` to `operation`.

Originally, I accomplished this by creating a Spark Job with a `main()` function that makes use of `myStream.foreachRDD()` and supplying the class name to `spark-submit` on the command-line, however, I would rather avoid making a call out-to-the-shell and instead: submit the job using the `streamingContext`.  This would both be more elegant and allow me to terminate the job, at will, simply by calling `streamingContext.stop()`.

I suspect that the solution is to make use of `streamingContext.sparkContext.runJob()` but this would require supplying additional arguments that I did not have to provide when using `spark-submit`: namely a single `RDD[T]` instance, and partition information.  Is there a sensible way to provide "default" values for these parameters (to mirror the utility of `spark-submit`) or is there another approach that I could be missing?

**Code Snippet**

```
val streamingContext : StreamingContext = ...
val eventStream : DStream[T] = ...

eventStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.toLocalIterator.toSeq.take(200).foreach { message =>
    message.foreach { content =>
      // process message content
    }
  }
}

streamingContext.start()
streamingContent.awaitTermination()
```

**Note:**

It is also acceptable (and possibly required) that only a specific time duration of the stream can be used as input for the submitted job.

Comment: For Spark in general, you can call SparkSubmit.scala main from inside your code with similar effects as calling spark-submit.sh, except that you'll miss on classpath settings and will have to take care of it yourself if you do so. There may a better  solution for Spark-streaming though